# Is there a name for an encryption scheme that do not return $\bot$ when a different key is used during decryption?

Tags: encryption, public-key, malleability

Given an encryption scheme $\Pi = (G,E,D)$, either public or private, is there a name or a property to emphasize that for $c\gets \Pi.E(k,m)$, where $k$ is a key and $m$ is a message, we want $m^\prime \neq \bot$ where $m^\prime \gets \Pi.D(k^\prime, c)$ with $k\neq k^\prime$? ($\bot$ here means *empty*)

Schemes such as Stream-Cipher (i.e., $E(k,m) = G(k)\oplus m$ with $G$ being a pseudorandom generator), RSA, ElGamal, etc. exhibit that property. At first, I thought it might be related to the notion of malleability, but a malleable encryption scheme allows one to compute a function $f(m)$ for a message $m$ given a ciphertext $c$ that encrypts $m$. Hence, it seems with malleable encryption, the same key is used.

Comment: "RSA ... exhibit[s] that property"; actually, the Bleichenbacker attack on RSA PKCS #1 encryption can be viewed as exploiting the lack of that property - that is, it assumes that the attacker can distinguish a decryption that results in a padding failure (hence, $\bot$) and a decryption that results in something...

Comment: The definition of deniable encryption might be of relevance here.

Answer (score 1):

If as you write *"we want"* this property, then I think the property is called *key equivocation*, which is supposed to make it harder for an attacker to distinguish the correct key from wrong ones.